# Zero Items Read In Output of Debug Mode

Tags: debug

I am attempting to troubleshoot a slow page by using the Debug option from Experience Editor.

The problem I'm facing is that it shows zero Items Read, which isn't helping me find the problem. In fact, all columns show zeroes. If I scroll further, literally every column all the way down shows zero.

[image: Zero Items Read]

`allowDebug="true"` is set to true on my `<site>` definition. I also toggled the main `<compilation debug="true"`, but it didn't make a difference.

It's impossible that no items are being read. Caching is disabled, but even then, it *has* to read a few items per call.

Sitecore 8.2u4

Is there another setting that I have disabled accidentally?

Comment: Is `enableDebugger` set to true on your site definition? And yes, that is a different setting than `allowDebug`.

Comment: That is set to `true` as well. In a higher environment, this works just fine so it must be config based in some way.

Comment: Just verified it works in all other environments correctly, just not my local. I'm able to advance with my tests by hijacking other environments. If I narrow it down to which specific config setting is busting this, I'll post the answer.

Comment: You are logged in as an admin user, yes?  the equivalent question to "is it plugged in?" :D

Comment: Yes, as admin. Added a new admin account as well to see if it was something fishy with my original account and still no dice.

Comment: I verified it is not related to our code base or database. I took a native install of 8.2u4, pointed it our database, still returned 0. Then took our code base and pointed towards the native install database and it returned 0. Must be something specific to my machine.

Comment: Also did not work on the vanilla install with vanilla databases, still showing zero items read.  Will bring up with support once I have some free cycles.